# How do I enable vlans in busybox when installing ubuntu server?

Tags: networking, server, system-installation, preseed, network-bonding

I'm trying to make a very specific iso for unattended installation, for that I need to use both bonding and vlans. I've been trying to make it work on 16.04, but I've also checked 18.04, so it doesn't seem to be version specific.

What I've found is, on a netinstall iso I can both use bonding and 8021q. 
But I there is no way to have it read preseed file from the iso file itself. And I do not know of a way to make both bond and vlan using the append (so that it can download preseed from the network and do the magic).

And on a full server iso, for some reason `modprobe bonding` and `modprobe 8021q` both produce an error: *module not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic*.

I've tried using `vconfig add eth0 5`
But that produces an error:
`vconfig: ioctl error for add: Package not installed`

I've also tried 
`ip link add link eth0 name eth0.5 type vlan id 5`
Which produces another error
`ip: RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported`

`ip link add bond0 type bond`
produces the same `ip: RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported`

It seems weird, that the **full 800mb iso** doesn't have the functionality of a mini iso, but maybe I'm missing something. An append parameter maybe? Because when I played around with append parameters, I somehow managed to get bonding to work on a full iso, althoug half of the things had to be done using `echo "+bond0" > /sys/class/net/bonding_masters` commands and the like...

TL;DR How can I use bonding and vlans on a full iso installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, `d-i` does something a bit weird here. 
If you turn off network configuration using
`d-i netcfg/enable boolean false`
most of the network stuff doesn't work, as network modules are not loaded.

What I did just to get vlans and bodning to work:

```
udpkg -i /cdrom/pool/main/l/linux/vlan*

insmod lib/modules/*/kernel/net/llc/llc.ko
insmod lib/modules/*/kernel/net/802/stp.ko
insmod lib/modules/*/kernel/net/802/garp.ko
insmod lib/modules/*/kernel/net/802/mrp.ko
insmod lib/modules/*/kernel/net/8021q/8021q.ko

modprobe bonding
```

for some reason `modprobe bonding` worked fine, but `modprobe 8021q` didn't work, even after `udpkg`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to  [@Leiocalyx answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1048308/790920) (sorry, rep won't allow me to add a comment)
after adding all this I had to set both interfaces up in order to make it work.

```
ip link set eth0 up
ip link set eth0.2 up
```

Cheers.